# Html div not being positioned

Tags: html, css

I am working on a small project just for my own fun. I have made a navbar at the top of the html page and I used some css to make it look nicer.

Here is the html

```
<html>
<head>
      <title> Website </title>
      <style type="text/css">
          body {
          margin: 0;
          background: #F2F2F2;
          }
          .navbar {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 45px;
          background: #12B0CD;
          position:fixed;
          }
          #navbar-logo {
          font-family:'Lato', Arial;
          font-size: 35px;
          color: white;
          border: none;
          background: #12B0CD;
          }
          .content {
          top: 50px;
          margin: none;
          width: 100%;
          height: 50%;
          z-index: -1;
          }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="navbar">
              <div id="navbar-logo">
                     <button id="navbar-logo">Fancy Name </button>
              </div>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
              <div id="content-box">
              </div>
       </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you pop this into notepad and open it in a browser you will see that the class content does not show and I don't know why. I need help. In the normal code I use stylsheets I don't know if that would change anything.

Comment: You're missing a closing `>` from `<div class="content-box"`, just FYI

Comment: I know i fixed it that was a type error on my part because I didn't copy and paste the code but thanks for responding

Comment: Why should the `content` element show? It is empty!

Comment: In html you can have the content be empty and set parameters for the box and change the background to make a blank box.

Comment: @ColbyHall - Okay, then why don't you do it?? :)

Comment: I did... look at the code

Comment: It is empty because it has no content. What do you expect to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your content box is empty, and you are using percentages, the box needs it's parent (body) to have a height. If you set, `width:100%;height:100%;` on your body you should see the box.